# Jenkinsfile custom docker container "could not find FROM instruction"

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I have just started working with Jenkinsfiles and Docker so apologies if this is something obvious.

I have a repo containing a Dockerfile and a Jenkins file.

The Dockerfile simply extends a base Ubuntu image (ubuntu:trusty) by adding several dependencies and build tools.

The Jenkinsfile currently only builds the Docker container for me:

```
node('docker') {
stage "Prepare environment"
    checkout scm
    docker.build('build-image')
}
```

When I run the Jenkins build, the output log shows the Docker container being successfully created, but just before it should finish successfully, I get:

```
Successfully built 04ba77c72c74
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintFrom
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
ERROR: could not find FROM instruction in /home/emackenzie/jenkins/workspace/001_test-project_PR-1-ROWUV6YLERZKDQWCAGJK5MQHNKY7RJRHC2TH4DNOZSEKE6PZB74A/Dockerfile
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have been unable to find any guidance on why I am getting this error from the internet, so any help would be greatly appreciated

---

Dockerfile:

```
FROM    ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Ed Mackenzie

# setup apt repos
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-get update

# python
RUN apt-get install -y python python-dev python-openssl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `FROM` line uses a tab for whitespace, instead of space(s). This is a bug in the Jenkins CI Docker workflow plugin, which expects the line to begin with `FROM` followed by a space.

From the [jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin) source on Github:

```java
String fromImage = null;

// ... other stuff

if (line.startsWith("FROM ")) {
    fromImage = line.substring(5);
    break;
}

// ... other stuff ...

if (fromImage == null) {
    throw new AbortException("could not find FROM instruction in " + dockerfile);
}
```

If you use spaces instead of tabs, it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran in to the same problem and it was a similar solution. Check if the file is encoded with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file (this can be done with something like Notepad++). If so, save it without the marker and the plugin will stop complaining.

Answer (score 1):

The error can be solved by changing the "from" statement to "FROM"

Comment: can you show a failure/pass case to support your answer?

Comment: Can confirm this fixed it for me.